# Weak entity with no primary key - hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a weak entity, which has foreign key, now i want one more column of this table to work as key along with foreign key to uniquely identify each row, how this can be achieved in hibernate?

```
class Task{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "trs_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "trs_generator", sequenc
eName = "TaskRunningStatus_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(nullable=false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long taskID;
    
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "identifier", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"))
    @Setter
    private List<Identifier> maxRecord;
    
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "identifier", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"))
    @Setter
    private List<Identifier> batchDoneRecord;
}

public class Identifier {

    private String key;
    private String value;
    private RecordType recordType;

    public enum RecordType{
        OFFSET, MAX
    }
    public Identifier(final String key, final String value, final RecordType recordType) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.recordType = recordType;
    }
}`
```

Identifier tables data look as below
[image]

Now after saving data in Task table for maxRecord(id,10,MAX) and batchDoneRecord(id,3,OFFSET). Later while fetching maxRecord or batchDoneRecord, it is returning all record for both as it is querying based on taskId.
This issue will be resolved if query is done based on both columns taskId and ReocrdType. How this can be achieved in hibernate?